# Pandas df read data source stored in ".xml?" page which is not in tables format?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I need to download the data table and export to excel in"http://www.dicj.gov.mo/web/en/information/DadosEstat_mensal/2019/index.html"  Inspecting the page using Chrome, inspect function. The data is in "http://www.dicj.gov.mo/web/en/information/DadosEstat_mensal/2019/report_en.xml?id=2". However, it is no longer in Table format.

```
url = "http://www.dicj.gov.mo/web/en/information/DadosEstat_mensal/2019/index.html"

table= pd.read_html(url)[2]
table.info()
print(table)
table.to_excel("GGR.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that now your source web site returns the content in XML format.

To process it, you can apply *BeautifulSoup*. Assuming that you have installed it,
proceed as follows:

1. Import necessary modules.

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests
   ```
2. Read the source page:

   ```
   page = requests.get('http://www.dicj.gov.mo/web/en/information/DadosEstat_mensal/2019/report_en.xml?id=2')
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
   ```
3. Read column names and create the MultiIndex for columns in the target DataFrame:

   ```
   col = soup.find_all('column')
   h1 = [ col[i].contents[0] for i in range(1,3) ]
   h2 = [ col[i].contents[0] for i in range(3,6) ]
   cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([h1, h2])
   ```
4. Process source records, creating *ind* (index) and *rows*:

   ```
   recs = soup.find_all('record')
   ind = []
   rows = []
   for rec in recs:
       cells = rec.find_all('data')
       ind.append(cells[0].contents[0])
       rows.append([ cells[i].contents[0] for i in range(1,7) ])
   ```
5. And the last step - create the target DataFrame:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(rows, index=ind, columns=cols)
   ```

I tried to read this table from the first page given by you, using *read_html*,
but I failed.
Probably the final content is loaded by some JavaScript in this page,
which can not be "seen" by *read_html*.